# Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, initialization

For my Comp Sci class I have to make a program that finds the number of days in the given month(1-12),  do ya'll know why I'm getting the error "variable days might not have been initialized" when trying to return the int "days" from the switch? Here's the code:

```
public static int getNumberofDays(int month,int year)
   {
      // Imports the required Scanner
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      final String month;
      final int days;
      switch (month) {
         case 1:  days = 31;
            break;
         case 2:  if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
                  {
                     days = 29;
                  }
                  else if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))
                  {
                     days = 29;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     days = 28;
                  }
            break;
         case 3:  days = 31;
            break;
         case 4:  days = 30;
            break;
         case 5:  days = 30;
            break;
         case 6:  days = 31;
            break;
         case 7:  days = 31;
            break;
         case 8:  days = 31;
            break;
         case 9:  days = 30;
            break;
         case 10: days = 31;
            break;
         case 11: days = 30;
            break;
         case 12: days = 31;
            break;
         default: month = "invalid";
            break;
      }
      return days;
   }
```

Comment: The code you posted is not accurate. This raises a different compilation error.

Comment: What a tricky question! So many mistakes in one method, very cool!

Answer (score 7):

> why I'm getting the error "variable days might not have been initialized"

Because:

```
final int days;
```

should be:

```
int days = 0;
```

Why?

- Variables in methods should be initialized
- Final variables cannot be modified.

---

## Other errors:

- You don't cover all possible values of `month` in `switch`
- you define a `String month`, shadowing the parameter `int month`
- The `Scanner` is unused
- many more... XD

---

## My solution using your way

Also, if you don't break a case block next one will be executed, that means you can do:

```
public static int getNumberofDays(int month,int year) {
    switch (month) {
       case 1:  
       case 3:  
       case 6:  
       case 7:  
       case 8:
       case 10: 
       case 12: 
             days = 31;
          break;
       case 4:
       case 5:
       case 9:
       case 11: 
             days = 30;
          break;
       case 2:  
          if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
          {
             days = 29;
          }
          else if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))
          {
             days = 29;
          }
          else
          {
             days = 28;
          }
          break;
       default: days = -1;
          break;
    }
    return days;
}
```

---

## My solution: [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)!:

```
public static int getNumberofDays(int month,int year)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
}
```

---

## [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467968/neil) solution: `Java-8`

```
public static int getNumberofDays(int month,int year)
{
    YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(year, month); 
    return yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();
}
```

Comment: Your repeated assignments are ugly and mean you can no longer use `final`.

Comment: @Neil agree, copy paste mistake, modified!!

Comment: @Bathsheba I dont use final, but agree about repeating statements... my mistake and fixed

Comment: We all missed the fact that `month` is passed as a function parameter.

Comment: @Bathsheba I didn't, please read my answer carefully I answer why the error, but also give solutions ignoring declaring variable again

Comment: But how can you switch on `month`, have integral types as the case labels, then assign `month` to a string in the `default` case?

Comment: because I reused OP answer, just updated to `days = -1`

Comment: @JordiCastilla although your suggestion to use `Calendar` is nice, it's not applicable to OP, since it's his task to write that method...

Comment: `int days = 0;` doesn't even look correct. There is no month with 0 days. :)

Comment: @BheshGurung please read before comment...

Comment: I read it, it's helpful for OP.

Comment: @radoh How you know OP task cannot be done by using calendar??? also. **His**? are you sure OP is a man? xDDDDD

Comment: Better still, Java 8's `YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(1999, 2);
int daysInMonth = yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();`

Comment: @JordiCastilla, `For my Comp Sci class I have to make a program ...`, you didn't read OP's question properly

Comment: @Neil Java-8 has it's own tag... what does not appear here

Comment: @radoh and????? you are committed to use plain java in Comp Sci Class??? maybe OP cannot use switch either and must use only if???

Comment: The usage of `Calendar` is of no use for OP, he is just getting started with variables.

Comment: @BheshGurung this is YOUR GUESS... not OP requirement in question...

Comment: @JordiCastilla ok, fair enough, I guess it's OP's task to clarify what he can/can't use.

Comment: @JordiCastilla So I take that to mean that all versions of Java are valid.  Someone stumbling onto this page using Java 8 is probably going to want to copy that huge switch statement into his program and not use the more proper solution.

Comment: @Neil agree with that... not `java-8` but `java-7` or `java-6` tags, so all versions are valid!

Comment: There is a duplicate variable (of different types) in the method, what does that suggest about the OP.

Comment: @Neil updated answer with your Java-8 suggestion

Comment: @JordiCastilla Kind of takes the fun out of a homework assignment though, doesn't it?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not all possible paths through your code assign a value to the days variable. Precisely the default block does not.

```
default: month = "invalid";
           break;
```

If you change it to

```
default: month = "invalid";
         days=0
           break;
```

The warning disappears.

My other questions are:

- Why do you define a String month, thus shadowing the parameter month?
- Whats the Scanner for?
- Why do you assign invalid to month in the default block, you never return it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `final String month;` is invalid since `month` is supplied as a parameter to the function.
2. You don't initialise `days` on all control paths: The `default` block in your `switch` doesn't do it. This is a nice feature of Java as it helps you achieve program stability. There's nothing better than the *compiler* telling you what to do. **Don't** force the issue by writing `final int days = 0;`; instead assign a value to it in the `default` block.

Comment: Especially now I've read the program more carefully

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Java 8 now allows you to do simply this to get days of month:  `YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(1999, 2);
int daysInMonth = yearMonthObject.lengthOfMonth();`

Comment: Indeed. I'm assuming (perhaps wildly) that this was a school exercise.

Comment: That seems accurate, but god forbid that a professional programmer stumble onto this page and copy that huge switch statement into his program.

Answer (score -2):

Add `days = 0;` to your default case, as such:

```
default: 
    month = "invalid";
    days = 0;
        break;
```

You have to give `days` a value somewhere in the code path before you try to return it. You should also replace `final int days;` with `int days;`. 
Also, you cannot have `final String month` because `month` is passed as a parameter to the function.. just remove the redeclaration of `month` and you're golden.

Comment: It would fix it, but an explanation as to why would be nice.  Edit:  I take that back, this would only fix one of the two problems.

Comment: duh.. I need my morning coffee as well

Comment: okay okay easy with the downvotes.. savages lol